# Zookeeper unable to talk to new Kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In an attempt to reduce the storage on my AWS instance I decided to launch a new, smaller instance and setup Kafka again from scratch using the Ansible playbook we had from before. I then terminated the old, larger instance and took its IP address that it and the other brokers were using and put it on my new instance.

When tailing my Zookeeper logs however I'm receiving this error -

```
2018-04-13 14:17:34,884 [myid:2] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@810] - Connection broken for id 1, my id = 2, error =
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:153)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:211)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:795)
2018-04-13 14:17:34,885 [myid:2] - WARN  [RecvWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$RecvWorker@813] - Interrupting SendWorker
2018-04-13 14:17:34,884 [myid:2] - WARN  [SendWorker:1:QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker@727] - Interrupted while waiting for message on queue
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2095)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:389)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.pollSendQueue(QuorumCnxManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.access$500(QuorumCnxManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$SendWorker.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:715)
```

I double checked and all 3 Kafka broker IP addresses are correctly listed in these location and I restarted all their services to be safe.

```
/etc/hosts
/etc/kafka/config/server.properties
/etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg
/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```